# Xamarin Forms Calculate Element bounds

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using Pinch and Pan gesture recognizer which wraps my image to zoom and move image on the screen. Calculation I've took from guide [Gesture pinch for zooming](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/pinch/) and [Gesture pan for moving](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/gestures/pan/).

Here simple calculation example for the pan:

```
 // Translate and ensure we don't pan beyond the wrapped user interface element bounds.
Content.TranslationX = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, xOffset + e.TotalX), -Math.Abs(Content.Width - App.ScreenWidth));
Content.TranslationY = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, yOffset + e.TotalY), -Math.Abs(Content.Height - App.ScreenHeight));
```

The issue is when I add an extra grid row above the row with wrapped image and I can zoom and move image that will stack on my grid row.

How can I calculate bounds for image in this case?

Comment: Is the gesture recognizer on the grid or the image? Can you reword your issue so better elaborate what the issue is. I am having a hard time following the sentence.

Comment: Much thanks for your reply. I will try to show my issue. Here I am having my Grid [Screenshot](http://joxi.ru/L214bd8t41LBmX) On top, with arrow I having first Row="0". When I am move image on top, it covers my first grid-row, like here [Screenshot](http://joxi.ru/KAxN97KHkOYGm8) How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you using container for having possibility to zoom or move any control you can restrict scale to move coordinates with bounds an coordinates with the container size and position.

Grid in Xamarin.Form only aligns elements inside according to configuration but it doesn't restrict farther controls modifications to aligh rect.

So in code where you perform scaling add condition which checks if the Content Width or Height is less or equal Container Width or Height.

The same with content movement. Stop changing Content Translation if Contents Rect falling out of the Conteiner Rect.